# Visual Studio + Jupyter: Failed to connect to Jupyter notebook. http://localhost:8888/ Error: Kernel Python 3.8.2 64-bit is not usable

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am able to connect to Jupyter Server in another Notebook.
But when I was trying to connect my current notebook for which vscode is failing to connect to Jupyter notebook.
Notebook is in a directory which is linked with git repo. I tried by cloning the repo in different folder but didn't work.

I also created an issue [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4937)

settings.json for working notebook is

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3"
}
```

settings.json for not working notebook is

```
{
"files.associations": 
   {
    "deque": "cpp",
    "string": "cpp",
    "vector": "cpp"
   },
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3"
}
```

I am sharing the Output here [image]

```
    Error 2021-02-24 14:19:05: DataScience Error [i [Error]: 
    at new t.WrappedError (/home/ubuntu/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/out/client/extension.js:1:153031)
    at /home/ubuntu/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/out/client/extension.js:32:654636
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)

Error: Kernel Python 3.8.2 64-bit is not usable. Check the Jupyter output tab for more information.
    at w.createNewKernelSession (/home/ubuntu/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/out/client/extension.js:49:554995)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async w.connect (/home/ubuntu/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/out/client/extension.js:49:554404)
    at async m.startNew (/home/ubuntu/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/out/client/extension.js:49:549756)
    at async _.connect (/home/ubuntu/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/out/client/extension.js:49:520500)
    at async /home/ubuntu/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/out/client/extension.js:32:653463] {
  category: 'invalidkernel',
  originalException: [c [Error]: Kernel Python 3.8.2 64-bit is not usable. Check the Jupyter output tab for more information.
    at w.createNewKernelSession (/home/ubuntu/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/out/client/extension.js:49:554995)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async w.connect (/home/ubuntu/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/out/client/extension.js:49:554404)
    at async m.startNew (/home/ubuntu/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/out/client/extension.js:49:549756)
    at async _.connect (/home/ubuntu/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/out/client/extension.js:49:520500)
    at async /home/ubuntu/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/out/client/extension.js:32:653463] {
    category: 'invalidkernel',
    kernelConnectionMetadata: {
      kind: 'startUsingKernelSpec',
      interpreter: [Object],
      kernelSpec: [a]
    }
  }
}
> /usr/bin/python3 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py vscode_datascience_helpers.daemon --daemon-module=vscode_datascience_helpers.jupyter_daemon -v
> /usr/bin/python3 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-toolsai.jupyter-2021.2.576440691/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py vscode_datascience_helpers.daemon --daemon-module=vscode_datascience_helpers.jupyter_daemon -v
```

Comment: Have you checked the Jupyter output tab for more information?

Comment: why is it not possible to post the text of the screen

Comment: I just pasted Jupyter Output

Comment: @Foysal Khandakar Joy -Is the dependency package "ipykernel" of Jupyter notebook installed in the current python environment?

Comment: Yes. I also ran the notebook through browser. Got the same issue. It failed to connect to the notebook.

Comment: Hi @everyone . So, I found a solution.
If I run from different window of vscode and not being in the directory of the notebook, it runs smoothly.

So, Kernel is failing when I run being at the same directory in a window.
And the problem is in the directory for all .ipynb and also .py file I recently noticed.